# Can priests in Krynn cast spells without their Medallion of Faith?

Tags: dragonlance

I'd read some books of the Dragonlance saga a long time ago, and now I'm doing some research to refresh my memory on some of the details.

IIRC, the names of the True Gods where known in Ansalon after the Cataclysm. Yet, the gods seemed to have forgotten their people. The Company of the Lance (through Goldmoon) had to find the [Disks of Mishakal](http://dragonlancenexus.com/lexicon/index.php?title=Disks_of_Mishakal), and through them, they learned about the gods, the rites and the like.

What confuses me now, is if all priests (including the ones of evil gods such as Takhisis, who were bringing the War of the Lance over Ansalon) each had to have one [Medallion of Faith](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Dragonlance_artifacts#Medallion_of_Faith) in order to cast spells.

So my question is: **have priests in the world of Krynn always needed their medallions of faith to cast spells** (both pre and post cataclysm)?

Also, lets try to include Ansalon and Taladas, but we can forget about the latter if all the answers we might get are just about RPG rules and references.

Comment: From the Cataclysm up until Goldmoon rediscovered the Disks of Mishakal was a time when priests/clerics did not have access to divine magic. This was part of the punishment (im unsure if it was a byproduct of the cataclysm, been years since I read the series) by the gods that began with the Cataclysm when Istar (Ishtar?) and its kingpriest was destroyed with the fiery mountain. Priests access divine magic through their faith in a certain god/ess and a medallion isn't needed for this (but I belive the medallion is gifted to the cleric from his/her god, I might be wrong on that)

Comment: @dai, well, I'm not sure about the relationship of the Medallions with the Disks. Why had the Disks to be rediscovered in order for the True Gods to grant spells again? Did this apply to evil priests, since Takhisis had her own agenda?

Comment: IIRC, the Medallions have nothing to do with the ability of clerics to cast spells in the books.  As I recall, when the cleric obtains the ability to cast spells, a Medallion is given to them by some divine means.  It's more of symbol of having obtained the faith necessary to cast spells granted by their deity.  But it's been a long time since I've read them all.

Comment: @BBlake, probably you are right. I'll have to do more research on why the Disks of Mishakal had to be discovered in order or the True God to say "OK, before no, but **now** lets start granting spell-like favors to the people who request them". And again, with the evils gods having their own agenda, so they might have been granting favors even before that?

Comment: I think the disks were required because no one left alive still believed in the truth about the gods.  They all believed the gods were gone, or dead, or whatever.  Only rumors and stories remained.  The true, correct belief system no longer existed on Krynn.  In order to restore that faith, someone needed to have a record which detailed the "true" faith.  Of course, the gods could have just re-revealed that faith to someone, but I would guess they wanted someone to prove that they really wanted the truth first.

Comment: @BBlake I'm a bit of an expert on Dragonlance and your last comment is 100% correct, you deserve the answer credit, please post.

Comment: @Ender, well I was hopen someone could elaborate about how it applies to evil priests, since a guy caller Aryakas had already taken over half Ansalon, under the guidance of Takhisis by the time the Companios discovered the Disks. IIRC, priest are needed in order to hatch good dragons eggs into draconians.

Comment: well as @BBlake said the gods could have revealed their faith to someone anytime they wanted to, but they were waiting for someone to prove they wanted it properly. Takhisis exercised her perogative to take initiative.

Comment: specifically she took advantage of the rest of the gods stubbornness to sieze control of the situation while they were almost literally doing nothing, creating the situation stated: she had an established foundation of strength before the rest of the gods even got involved

Comment: @Deion - Your recollection is correct.  It required both evil priests and black robe wizards to corrupt and hatch the dragon eggs into Draconian soldiers.

Answer (score 4):

**TL:DR:** According to D&D-4e, **yes** they can... but there's no in-universe precedent for it.

This is mostly a deconstruction of your Wiki link. As, I have of yet to find, an instance where a cleric does so without theirs. I believe there was a point at which Crysania's prayers were unanswered, but that was from a lack of faith, not a misplaced necklace. I'm still looking for a part that says, "the Schwartz are in *you!"* - Skip to the last paragraph for the D&D rules.

What follows is an interpretation by one who has come to understand D&D, largely in part, through the epic saga that is *Dragonlance*. **Beware the wall of text**, offering no input on 'pre/post cataclysm'.

---

To start off, let's first look at another definition with the keywords, *outward sign*: (and a hint at the reasoning behind the lack of precedence for an answer)

> This is a cleric's outward sign for their commitment and faith toward their god or goddess. [...] The Medallions also resist any effort to be removed by force from the cleric. It usually results in a severely shocked or burned hand. –Medallion of Faith, [dragonlancenexus.com](http://dragonlancenexus.com/lexicon/index.php?title=Medallion_of_Faith)

**Medallion of Faith** –[List of Dragonlance artifacts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Dragonlance_artifacts#Medallion_of_Faith) –Wiki:

(They "provide an outlet to channel power from". It does *not* say 'provides a means from which clerics cast spells'.)

> Medallions of faith are worn by the members of the clergy of the true gods of Krynn, with the exception of the three gods of magic. These medallions are worn to serve two purposes; one is to proclaim the faith of the wearer, and, in the case of clerics, to provide an outlet to channel power from. Medallions of faith can be worn by the common citizenry, but they do not gain clerical power from the medal. The medallions are magical. The Medallions have a symbol of the god upon them. Medallions are used in conjunction with robes and vestments to display the nature and deity of the cleric.

Let's take a closer look:

> can be worn by the common citizenry, but they do not gain clerical power from the medal.

With that wording, one might assume that the faithful *do* gain clerical powers, however:

> Medallions are used in conjunction with robes and vestments to display the nature and deity of the cleric.

Channeling the power of a god requires faith above all else (and according to 'the rules', they need no such *implement*). No true cleric of Krynn requires magic to cast cleric spells:

> The medallions are magical.

You might think that *'clerics don't require magic'* requires a cite, so I'll let Raist handle that: (if you've a problem with *'requires faith above all else'*, ask your local theologian about it, as I am ill-prepared to defend that part)

> Raistlin Majere: She's channeling the power of a god, you dolt. I'm wresting arcane energies from the very fabric of the universe - it's completely different. –[IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0825245/quotes)

**Editorial:** (including a non-definitive example of a cleric without one, and AFAIK the only time this occurs)

Rephrase:
Can a 'priest' in Krynn personally cast cleric spells without ever having *Been Given* a Medallion of Faith?

IMO, absolutely not. No self-respecting god would forget to bestow their *symbol* of faith before granting that *power*. You might find cites to the contrary, but they would be far from the norm.

I'd surmise, that it's going to be difficult to find a passage, in which a cleric without their medallion is *not* also experiencing a lapse of faith. For, in but the one example I've found, I sincerely doubt that when "Crysania gave her Medallion of Faith to Palin to get past the grove"*, Paladine deserted her even momentarily.

Such earthly trinkets have no effect on the prerogative of someone who's literally been through hell and back. Someone of less faith however, might feel the need for such a bauble, and probably performs poorly without one.

**Lack of precedence:**

Lastly, this situation simply doesn't happen unwillingly:

> Brigands attacked them, and when one of them named Steeltoe attempted to remove her Medallion of Faith, it harmed him.*

Yours is a valid question, but exactly *why* it isn't around their neck is integral to the answer. Tantamount to sacrilege, no person of continuing faith is ever without theirs, willingly - without a reason in good faith.

Permit me one last bit of speculation, that the prayers of those who have willingly discarded their medallion, surely go unanswered. If you *are* worthy, it *is* around your neck - there is no nominal precedent for one without the other.

Unfortunately, the one cleric who would be most apt to ignore this rule if it does exist, is also one and the same as our only example: Crysania. So, in lieu of emailing the authors, we can but look up the rules.

*: Crysania Tarinius, [dragonlancenexus.com](http://dragonlancenexus.com/lexicon/index.php?title=Crysania_Tarinius)

---

**D&D rules:**

*Which cleric powers are usable without a Holy Symbol?* –[RPG.SE](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/11801/which-cleric-powers-are-usable-without-a-holy-symbol), paraphrased:

> Clerics can use (almost) all of their powers when disarmed and without implements. With which, you would simply get a bonus (in D&D-4e).

Comment: In the 3e/3.5e version of the Dragonlance setting, priests *did* require a medallion of faith in order to cast spells. Fortunately, any priest with access to the *bless* spell (and a medallion of their own) could make more medallions, and the *bless* spell was first level, so they were pretty easy to get ahold of if lost, stolen, or encountered-for-the-first-time-after-centuries-of-divine-absence.

Comment: @user867 - Is there a Dragonlance version of 3e/3.5e, or does it simply adhere to those rules? If you have a cite that they *did*, I implore you to answer (or gimme teh codez, plz!)

Comment: Dragonlance for 3/3.5e D&D was an officially-licensed product line, but a third-party one. (Or possibly a second-party one, depending on who you ask.) Which is to say, it wasn't made by WOTC, but by another group (Sovereign Press) with the legal right to do so. I understand Margaret Weiss was involved, and her name is a powerful talisman. Anyway, I can't provide a reference for the thing about needing a medallion of faith because I don't own copies of the books; I once came across a paragraph to that effect while flipping through a friend's copy, and it stuck in my mind.

Answer (score 0):

Magic is given to Deitys by Solinari the white moon,lunitari the red and Nuitari,they are physically moons...
Their spellbook library is atop the Silver stairs... Without passing the Test at Wayreth the gods don't allow you to cast spells over 3rd level...
Before the cataclysm,A cleric came to see every true faith cleric in the land, and brought them all,from 21 gods, with him into their god's own thereafter...the all left with their medallions, medallions can be created by other medallions or by reading the disks of mishakkal...so without the medallions,no clerical spell above 3rdLvl is not out of reach for everyone without a medallion of Faith...

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  What is your source for this?